# Continuous in punctured ball, bounded implies can be continuously extended?

Tags: continuity, harmonic-functions

If $n\geq 3$ and $f: B_1(0)\setminus\{0\}:\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded, then can $f$ be defined at $x=0$ so that $f$ is continuous on $B_1(0)$? I believe this should be true but I am not sure how to show it.

This is just one step in this problem: If $u$ is harmonic in $B_1(0)\setminus\{0\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} |x|^{n-2}u(x)=0$, then $u\in C^2(B_1(0))$. Here $n\geq 3$.

I was able to show that this condition implies that $u$ is bounded. But I am wondering if it can then be redefined at $x=0$ so that it is continuous? Then I was thinking to use the Mean Value Property to show that $u$ is $C^2$. So if it helps, we can assume that $f$ is harmonic as well.

Comment: It's definitely not true generally, as $f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{1}{|x|^n}\right)$ would be a counterexample. But with harmonic functions we can use mean value property as you said.

Comment: Ok so we clearly need more than continuity. But how would you go about using the MVP anyway? In order to show that $f\in C^2$, we need to show that $f$ satisfies the MVP around $x=0$ right? How can we use MVP around the other points to conclude that it holds at $x=0$?

Comment: You define a new function $g$ with the value at the origin being defined as $g(0) = \frac{\int_B f dx}{\int_B dx}$ and $g(x) = f(x)$ everywhere else. It should be an easy proof that the choice of ball does not matter as long as it is centered at $0$. $f$ automatically satisfies MVP everywhere else because it is harmonic.

Comment: $f$ satisfies MVP everywhere else with the domain being the punctured ball. Why can we now say that $f$ satisfies MVP with the domain being the whole ball? Am I missing something?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, it's ok if $f$ is harmonic. And yes, the extended function must be given by $g(0)=$ what you said. And yes, it follows that $g$ satisfies MVP everywhere. But things are not quite as simple as you seem to think: To  show that MVP for $g$ implies that $g$ is harmonic we also need to know that $g$ is _continuous_...

Comment: Yes... that can be done...as well as showing that MVP holds for $r>|x|$ when $|x|<1/2$ is a similar proof to what is done below

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the question in the title:

$f(x)=\frac {x_1} {\|x\|}$ is a counterexample. Note that $f$ does not have a limit at the origin along the $x_1$ axis.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.